# load wordpress from non default 'main.php' file

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have my WordPress site up and running, I want to make some changes in order to whenever I type 'mydomain.com' the 'main.php' or 'index2.php' compared to 'index.php' starts the WordPress.

In other words, I want to rename my default 'index.php' to 'index2.php'. that's because I want to put another 'index.php' that is not relevant to WordPress at all. after that the user can access the WordPress by typing 'mydomain.com/index2.php'.

What should I do for that?

Comment: I would really like to help but question is hard to understand

Comment: You’d first of all need to change the basic rewriting logic WP uses, so that for routing purposes it passes all relevant requests to that script file, instead of the index.php as is the default. (But careful, if you would simply modify the WP section of the .htaccess file to achieve this, WordPress will overwrite it the next time it updates the .htaccess.) Why do you want to do this in the first place? Do you imagine that would increase security somehow …?

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I want to change httaccess or wp-config.php to whenever I type 'mydomain.com/index2.php' the real index2.php on disk loads wordpress. Suppose I want to rename my default 'index.php' to 'index2.php' and put another 'index.php' that is not relevant to wordpress at all.

Comment: Question is too unclear to answer it.

Answer (score 0):

You can change default DirectoryIndex by .htaccess, So instead of loading `index.php` in default it can be load `main.php` or `index2.php`.

```
DirectoryIndex main.php
```

OR

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

whatever the file you named.

Comment: That's OK, but in this way how can I load my old wordpress weblog at all? In this way the new introduced file will load.

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean?

Comment: If I type 'mydomain.com' the non wordpress 'index.php' loads
If I type 'mydomain.com/index2.php' the wordpress main page loads

Comment: If you want to load non-WordPress to the domain changing `DirectoryIndex` AND if you rename WordPress main `index.php` to `index2.php` then WordPress will be loaded in `index2.php` but all URLs will still refer to root path `/`.